# Lambda Snapstart with Kinesis Trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to reduce the cold start time taken for lambda startup by integrating Snapstart, having seen around the blogs and tutorials, it is fine integrating for apis. Do Snapstart really support static initiation of spring boot application with kinesis as trigger.

Static initiation of spring boot with awsproxy was implemented and working as expected.
How do we route the kinesis trigger to awsproxy request or is there any other ways to achieve it.